My extern USB ext4 harddisk had only user #1000 rights
My external USB ext4 hard drive only has user #1000 rights, so I can't write or copy to/from the disk (can't change this with properties either)
Have newly installed 24.04
I wish the rights were mine so I could perform these actions
Any suggestions on what I can try?

How is it mounted? Type the terminal command mount, and pick the right line. I suspect exfat filesystem.  Read man mount, paying particular attention to the EXFAT section.

Find out where your external USB ext4 hard drive is mounted.
Let's say it's in:  /media/user/mydisk
Give it the necessary permissions using the chmod command.
(man chmod will tell you how this command works)
To give it the necessary permissions run in a terminal
   sudo chmod -Rf 755 /media/user/mydisk


If sdb1 or sdb2 is a system partition, good way to destroy system. -R is recursive so all files & subfolders are changed. And 777 is wide open permissions, so not so safe just like Windows.  User 1000 is the correct default admin user. Better to have posted details like. sudo parted -l and lsblk-f so we do not post incorrect commands.

I think better to use chown -R $USER: /media/user/mydisk. Your solution does not grant write permissions if you are not the owner.
